# How can I filter my items through a radio input?

Tags: angular

I have an array with a series of elements that correspond to 3 animals. I have 3 radio input to filter these animals. I would like that when you select a radio input from a specific animal, the other animals disappear. But in the event that you select the "show all" option, all are shown. What is the best way to do it?

I wanted to ask this question because maybe there is some way to do it all from the view, without having to do a loop or something like that in the component.

**component.html**

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio_option" [(ngModel)]="radio_option" value="all" /> show all
<input type="radio" name="radio_option" [(ngModel)]="radio_option" value="horse" /> Horse
<input type="radio" name="radio_option" [(ngModel)]="radio_option" value="chicken" /> Chicken
<input type="radio" name="radio_option" [(ngModel)]="radio_option" value="cat" /> Cat
<p *ngFor="let item of options">
  {{ item.animal }}
</p>
```

**component.ts**

```js
const options: any[] = [
  {
    animal: 'horse'
  },
  {
    animal: 'chicken'
  },
  {
    animal: 'cat'
  },
  {
    animal: 'horse'
  },
  {
    animal: 'chicken'
  },
  {
    animal: 'cat'
  }
];
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'other animals disappear'? Do you want to hide the list of animals below inside the p tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like below:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of options">
     <p *ngIf="radio_option==item.animal || radio_option=='all'">
          {{item.animal}}
     </p>
</ng-container>
```

It will show that animal only if show all is selected or that specific animal is selected

Comment: excellent thanks. This answers my question. Only one last doubt. If I had more radio input with more animals that are not in my array ... How can I show a message indicating that there are no animals with that selection?

Comment: You can use ngSwitch instead of ngIf and add a default case stating no animals with that selection
If this answers your question, please make sure to accept it.

Comment: I updated the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xphzkm?file=src/app/app.component.ts   How can I show a message indicating that there are no animals with that selection? (In my real code I have "n" input radios)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583030/include-message-when-filter-by-radio-input-does-not-show-matches can you help me please?

Comment: Refer to [comment 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582572/how-can-i-filter-my-items-through-a-radio-input/54582706?noredirect=1#comment95962760_54582706)